# How to transform markdown to html like the plugin gatsby-transformer-remark does (for NetlifyCMS)

Tags: html, markdown, gatsby, converters, netlify-cms

I'd like to transform a markdown string to html the same way as the [plugin gatsby-transformer-remark](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-transformer-remark/) does.

So far I used [showdown](https://www.npmjs.com/package/showdown). This works ok, but it's missing features like transforming the [image editor component](https://www.netlifycms.org/docs/widgets/#markdown).

I'd like to transform markdown with the same alghorithm as the plugin gatsby-transformer-remark.

Is there a ready made solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reverse-engineering gatsby-transformer-remark, I found this solution:

```
const remark = require(`remark`);
const mdastToHast = require(`mdast-util-to-hast`);
const hastToHtml = require(`hast-util-to-html`);

const remarker = new remark();

const markdownAst = remarker.parse(data.body);
const htmlAst = mdastToHast(markdownAst, { allowDangorousHtml: true });
const htmlRaw = hastToHtml(htmlAst, { allowDangorousHtml: true });

const html = htmlRaw
  .split('<img src="uploads/')
  .join('<img src="/uploads/');
```